# Use method in entity framework query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-6

Is there anyway around this error? I'd like to reuse the same lamba expression in other queries instead of having duplication. Can LinqKit or other linq expression do this?

Error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean GetEvent(Tournaments.Data.Entities.Event, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Code

```
public MobileEventDetailModel GetDetails(string applicationId)
{
    var @event = (from e in _eventsRepository.DataContext.Events.Include(q => q.Assets.Select(a => a.Asset))
                  where GetEvent(e, applicationId)
                select new
                    {
                        e.Id,
                        e.EventParent.Name,
                        LogoId = (from a in e.Assets
                                     where a.Type   == EventAssetType.Logo
                                     select a.AssetId).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

    return new MobileEventDetailModel
        {
            Id = @event.Id,
            Name = @event.Name,
            Logo = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Config.BaseUrl, Config.ImagesPath, @event.LogoId)
        };
}

public bool GetEvent(Event @event, string applicationId)
{

    return @event.Active && @event.Visible && @event.MobileEventApplications.Any(m =>
                          m.MobileApplication.ApplicationId == applicationId &&
                          (!m.MobileApplication.ActivationLength.HasValue || EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, 1) < EntityFunctions.AddMonths(m.MobileApplication.DateActivated, m.MobileApplication.ActivationLength.Value)));
}
```

Comment: I dont think that LINQkit or anyother extension can help. You cannot use methods or functions from .net because they cannot be translated to SQL. You can use SqlFunctions which include standard Sql Server functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Expression:

```
public MobileEventDetailModel GetDetails(string applicationId)
{

    var event = _eventsRepository.DataContext.Events.Include(q => q.Assets.Select(a => a.Asset))
                .Where(GetEvent(applicationId))
                .Select(a =>  new
                    {
                        a.Id,
                        a.EventParent.Name,
                        LogoId = (from b in a.Assets
                                     where b.Type == EventAssetType.Logo
                                     select b.AssetId).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

    return new MobileEventDetailModel
        {
            Id = event.Id,
            Name = event.Name,
            Logo = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Config.BaseUrl, Config.ImagesPath, event.LogoId)
        };
}

public Expression<Func<Event, bool>> GetEvent(int applicationId)
{
    return = a => a.Active 
                  && a.Visible 
                  && a.MobileEventApplications
                      .Any(m => m.MobileApplication.ApplicationId == applicationId 
                                && (!m.MobileApplication.ActivationLength.HasValue 
                                    || EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, 1) 
                                       < EntityFunctions
                                         .AddMonths(m.MobileApplication.DateActivated, m.MobileApplication.ActivationLength.Value)
                                   )
                      );
}
```

Update: Sorry it was late the other night, the changed version is hopefully more what you were looking for.